# TypeScript and this context detection

Tags: typescript

When I add this code inside the constructor (`start` is the method of the class):

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener, event => {
    this.start();
};
```

TypeScript is smart enough to know that context of this changes inside the callback:

```
var _this = this;
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener, function (event) {
    _this.start();
};
```

However, when I change it to use `$("#test").click` , `this` is not held in helper variable anymore, and code will break:

```
$("#test").on("click", function () {
    this.start();
});
```

How is it working that in the former example TypeScript does the right thing, but in the latter it does not?

Comment: Why not just use arrow functions to prevent it: `$("#test").on("click", () => {`

Comment: Yeap, I didn't know about it => expressions work this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as-designed. TypeScript binds the `this` reference to the containing class in arrow-functions, but uses the JavaScript meaning of `this` in `function(){}` functions. See, ad infra, http://piotrwalat.net/arrow-function-expressions-in-typescript/. In other words, the problem isn't with the `addEventListener` vs the `.on('click')` syntax, but the fact that in the second, you were using a `function(){}` instead of an arrow function.

Answer (score 2):

It's because in one it's using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)...

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener(event => {
    this.start();
});
```

...and the other is using a function expression...

```
$("#test").on("click", function() {
    this.start();
});
```

To fix it, change the callback to an arrow function:

```
$("#test").on("click", () => {
    this.start();
});
```