# Angular 2: Bootstrap Switch not changing value of variable

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, bootstrap-switch

I'm using bootstap switches for checkboxes in my Angular 2 application. When you click on the switch, I want the value of my `LightNeeded` variable in my class to change along with it. I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<input class="bootstrap-switch light-needed" name="LightNeeded" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="LightNeeded">
```

TypeScript file:

```
LightNeeded: boolean;

 ngOnInit(): void {        
    // Invoke bootstrap switches
    $('.bootstrap-switch').bootstrapSwitch({
        onText: "Yes",
        offText: "No"
    });
    this.changeBootstrapSwitchValues();
}

changeBootstrapSwitchValues() {
    $('.light-needed').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event:any, state:any) {
        if (state) {  
            console.log('true');
            this.LightNeeded= true;
        } else {  
            console.log('false');
            this.LightNeeded= false;
        };
    });
}
```

When switch is true, it successfully logs true to the console. When it is false, it successfully logs false to the console. However, it never changes the value of my `LightNeeded` variable.

When I hover over `this` of `this.LightNeeded`, I get the following warning:

> suspicious 'this' usage: in current context 'this' refers to a local
>   function, not to a containing class.

How can I get `this` to work the way I am intending and change the value of my `LightNeeded` variable? I'm open to taking other approaches that make sense too. I tried adding `[attr.checked]="LightNeeded? true : null"` to my input, but it didn't work.

**EDIT:**

The two-way binding from adding `[(ngModel)]="LightNeeded"` worked when it was a simple checkbox, but for some reason the bootstrap switch plugin breaks that two-way binding. Other plugins such as JQuery Inputmask and JQuery UI Datepicker also break two-way binding.

Comment: the value will be changed by two-way binding of the element

Comment: It should be, yes, but it isn't. It worked when they were simple checkboxes, but as soon as I implemented the bootstrap switch the two-way binding broke.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript and this context detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33791128/typescript-and-this-context-detection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your event handler function changes the context of `this`. Instead, you should use an arrow function, which does not change context/binding. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Example:

```
$('.light-needed').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', (event:any, state:any) => {
        if (state) {  
            console.log('true');
            this.LightNeeded= true;
        } else {  
            console.log('false');
            this.LightNeeded= false;
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's all about function scoping. `this` keyword inside your `changeBootstrapSwitchValues()` function refers to JQuery object. You can fix this using following technique;

```
changeBootstrapSwitchValues() {
let self = this;
    $('.light-needed').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event:any, state:any) {
        if (state) {  
            console.log('true');
            //this.LightNeeded= true;
            self.LightNeeded= true;
        } else {  
            console.log('false');
            //this.LightNeeded= false;
            self.LightNeeded= false;
        };
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is to late but I made a component for angular2+ called  [jw-boostrap-switch-ng2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2) if anyone want to check it out.

Is better solution to implement a component because you don't have to worry about JQUERY.