# angular2 onclick call method service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, onclick, http-post

I have a button component that has to call a function on event click:

```
<button pButton type="button" label="Add EchoBeacon" (click)="insertPoint()">
 constructor(private mappaService: MappaService) {}
...
insertPoint() {
    this.map.removeInteraction(this.interaction);
    this.select.getFeatures().clear();
    this.map.removeInteraction(this.select);
    this.interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
      type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ 'Point',
      source: this.echoBeacons.getSource()
    });
    this.map.addInteraction(this.interaction);
    this.interaction.on('drawend', function(e) {
      var feature = e.feature;
      var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
      this.coordinates = geometry.getCoordinates();
      this.mappaService.savePoint(this.coordinates[0], this.coordinates[1])
         .subscribe(
            data => console.log('Added'),
            error => console.error('Error: ' + error),
            () => console.log('Completed!')
         );

}
```

and this is the method service :

```
savePoint(x: number, y :number): Observable<any[]>{
  let headers      = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  let options       = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  let serverPostDbUrl ="http://172.16.32.1:3000/beacon";
  let body = `{"x": ${x}, "y": ${y}}`;
  return this.http.post(`${serverPostDbUrl}`, body, options)
    .map((res:Response) => res.json())
    .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || "Server error"));

}
```

but when I click on button, console logs me that 'cannot read a property of undefined', like mappaService isn't defined in insertPoint() function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: Bootstrap Switch not changing value of variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517580/angular-2-bootstrap-switch-not-changing-value-of-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with this line: `this.interaction.on('drawend', function(e) {`

Using regular functions definitions will change the context of this, so that it will no longer be the Component/Service. You will need to use [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to maintain `this`.

ie.

```
this.interaction.on('drawend', (e) => {
```